# Return value of ProxyManager\Configuration::setGeneratorStrategy() must be an instance of ProxyManager\void, none returned

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, php-7.2

I am using Symfony framework 3.4 at the moment. My vagrant box is running PHP 7.2.2. I everything was working properly before i installed 3 bundles below:

1. almasaeed2010/adminlte
2. doctrine/data-fixtures
3. doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle

I am getting below error when i am trying to access any page:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Type error: Return value of ProxyManager\Configuration::setGeneratorStrategy() must be an instance of ProxyManager\void, none returned

in Configuration.php (line 108)
at Configuration->setGeneratorStrategy(object(EvaluatingGeneratorStrategy))
in RuntimeInstantiator.php (line 37)
at RuntimeInstantiator->__construct()
in Kernel.php (line 828)
at Kernel->getContainerBuilder()
in Kernel.php (line 770)
at Kernel->buildContainer()
in Kernel.php (line 642)
at Kernel->initializeContainer()
in Kernel.php (line 137)
at Kernel->boot()
in Kernel.php (line 197)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in app_dev.php (line 29)
```

I did some google about this error and i found that people with older PHP version or older version of `ocramius/proxy-manager` was having the problem. But none helped me to solve this issue and now i am stuck.

Hope i will find some solution for this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your application is running on 7.2.2? did you check in your symfony profiler?

Comment: Hi @IwanWijaya yes i checked both profiler and also php --version and the output was PHP 7.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running PHP 7.2, not even 7.1, because the `void` type is not recognized. Check again your Vagrant configuration.

Comment: Hi, i can give u screen capture of my `php --version` command which will be php-cli. The one thing i am not sure is that if my app also running same as php-cli version.

Comment: yes you are right, for some weird reason, even i updated PHP version to 7.2.2 and also configured my apache2 server to run on 7.2.2 and deleted old 7.0.1 which came default with my vagrant box, for some weird reason it was still running on PHP 7.0.1. I am reconfiguring the server again. Thank you.