# Docker-compose doesn't load PHP image

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

To be honest, I am new to Docker and I am going to run a web app built with symfony, but it seems like the PHP module is not running(It's my own opinion).
My docker file starts with `FROM php:7.0-apache` so I think it must run PHP files.
But when I access https://localhost to see the app, I get this error.
I am running this on Docker 19.03.1

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of ProxyManager\Configuration::setGeneratorStrategy() must be an instance of ProxyManager\void, none returned in /var/www/html/vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php:124
>
> Stack trace: 0 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/ProxyManager/LazyProxy/Instantiator/RuntimeInstantiator.php(37): ProxyManager\Configuration->setGeneratorStrategy(Object(ProxyManager\GeneratorStrategy\EvaluatingGeneratorStrategy))
>
> 1 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(732): Symfony\Bridge\ProxyManager\LazyProxy\Instantiator\RuntimeInstantiator->__construct()
>
> 2 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(680): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->getContainerBuilder()
>
> 3 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(573): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer()
>
> 4 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel in /var/www/html/vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php on line 124

I tried to clean my Docker images and ran again but I got no success with the same result.
Any help or advice is should be really appreciated. :)

Comment: That error will be generated by PHP so you definitely have a PHP running

Comment: Thanks so much! @riggsfolly Could you please explain me why this error turns out? I got stuck for long because of this.

Comment: I would if I could but I cant. Sorry

Comment: how you run this without docker? which version of PHP? the issue with php version and proxy manager. lock the packages. you also might need to update php php:7.2-apache. these link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243312/return-value-of-proxymanager-configurationsetgeneratorstrategy-must-be-an-in and https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager/issues/294

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return value of ProxyManager\Configuration::setGeneratorStrategy() must be an instance of ProxyManager\void, none returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243312/return-value-of-proxymanager-configurationsetgeneratorstrategy-must-be-an-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use at least php 7.1 to run that app.
You are using 7.0, try to update your container.

The `void` return type is not supported in php < 7.1, so you get the error about the `void` return type that instead is `null`.

You are probably using a symfony version which requires php >= 7.1

Comment: I'm sorry, I will explain it better, void return type is not supported in php < 7.1, so he gets the error about the void return type that instead is null. He's probably using a symfony version which requires php >= 7.1

Comment: Thanks so much! You saved me. @m4v1

Answer (score 2):

Symfony requires PHP 7.1 to run, as stated in the [requirements](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#technical-requirements).

But even 7.1 is already [out of active support](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), you should use the latest version 7.3.

To fix this, change your Dockerfile to

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
```

Also see this answer here: [Return value of ProxyManager\Configuration::setGeneratorStrategy() must be an instance of ProxyManager\void, none returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243312/return-value-of-proxymanager-configurationsetgeneratorstrategy-must-be-an-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)